# Watson IoT: "Extensions" entry is not available in left menu

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, cloudant, watson-iot

I've been following the [Gather, visualize, analyze and detect anomalies in IoT data](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-gather-visualize-analyze-iot-data) tutorial and, although I was able to go through it flawlessly, I'm stuck in the second step of the "Create a data connector to store the historical data" section. **In my Watson IoT left menu, there is no entry called "Extensions"**, my last option is the "Configuration" one. As far as I know, I have re-checked all the steps twice and I have tried to configure different regions (I'm located in Spain) for both Watson IoT and cloudant services (all within the "Lite" program), but I can't, for the life of me, forward the data received in Watson IoT to Cloudant.

Is there anything that has changed in the Watson IoT platform since the tutorial was written? Do I need to activate anything in my account that allows me to see the "Extensions" option?

Thank you for your support and if you need more information about my setup, don't hesitate to ask.

Best regards,

Aitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Solution tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-gather-visualize-analyze-iot-data#historical_data_connector),

> Setting up a new connection is a four-step process:
>
> - Create a service binding that provides Watson IoT Platform with the    necessary information to connect to the Cloudant service.
> - Create a connector instance for the service binding.
> - Configure one or more destinations on the connector.
> - Set up one or more forwarding rules for each destination.

You can refer to the [IBM Watson IoT Platform - Historical Data Storage Extension APIs](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002/historian-connector.html)
 swagger UI as mentioned in the tutorial.

You can also access the interactive API docs directly from the Watson IoT Platform service dashboard by selecting the menu bar help icon in the upper right corner of the window and then clicking **API** > historian connector > **View APIs**. To store the historical data to Cloudant, you will be passing the IBM Cloudant credentials to create a Watson IoT Platform service binding.

You can find the extensions deprecation information in the [post here](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2019/11/04/advanced-notice-withdrawal-of-iot-platform-service-extensions/)

Comment: The solution tutorial is updated with the latest information.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your fast and detailed answer and also for updating the tutorial!