# Watson IoT: Dashboard graphs cannot retrieve information from cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, cloudant, watson-iot

Continuing with my Watson IoT journey ([previous episode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275906/cant-connect-watson-iot-platform-to-cloudant)), I'm trying to add a line graph to my dashboard in order to view historical data in an easy way. But it seems that, with the recent [Extension service removal](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2019/11/04/advanced-notice-withdrawal-of-iot-platform-service-extensions/), it is not possible to view historical information in a widget. This is the message I see in the widget configuration page:

[Watson IoT Widget - Cloudant (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3kP3.png)

"No se han configurado bases de datos en la página de extensiones" -> "No databases have been configured on the extensions page".

I suppose that the configuration option needs to be modified to the new situation, right? Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Many thanks for your help and I'm sorry for my simple questions, please be patient with me

Best regards,

Aitor

Comment: you would need to do the similar steps as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275906/cant-connect-watson-iot-platform-to-cloudant

Comment: Hi @idan! Many thanks for your help and support, but sadly I think that your message does not answer to what I was asking. In my case, following the steps described in the "previous episode" link, I have been able to link my Watson IoT device data to Cloudant, the information is stored in the database. But I'm not able to visualize the historical data in a line or graph chart, because the widget cannot retrieve the information without the "Extension" service. Let's see if someone is able to shed some light on the issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I learnt from the team and also worked for me is to add a new `Forwarding rule` on the Swagger UI(OpenAPI spec) as mentioned in the [Stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184990/watson-iot-extensions-entry-is-not-available-in-left-menu)

The forwarding rule with the corresponding connectorId to be used as a model would be as shown below

```
{
 "name": "iot-cloudant-rule",
 "destinationName": "default",
 "type": "event",
 "selector": {
   "deviceType": "*",
   "eventId": "*"
  }
 }
```

If you observe, both the `deviceType` and `eventId` should be set to `*`. Once you execute the forwarding rule, you should see the Cloudant service name 
[image]